# ES6. access class variable from outsite class

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I'm having a problem getting the value of some vars from outside its class.
I want to access `attack` but it gets undefined for some reason. Anyone can help me here?

CODE:

index.js (from which I try to access the variable)

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Tone from 'tone'; 
import EnvelopeModule from './envelope.js';

$(document).ready(() => {

  const envelope = new EnvelopeModule();
  console.log(envelope.attack); //undefined

  initApp();
});
```

envelope.js (where I set the variable)

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Tone from 'tone';

export default class EnvelopeModule {
  constructor(attack) {
    this.attack = attack;
    this.init();        
  }

  init() {
    this.addListeners();
  }

  addListeners() {
    $('input#attack').on('input change', this.set);
  }

  set() {
    this.attack = $('input#attack').val()/100;
    let val = $(this).val()/100;
    $(this).prev().text(val);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `envelope` also `undefined`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox if `envelope` is `undefined` that might me an exception

Comment: It's not defined because its value is never assigned. Try `console.log(new EnvelopeModule("test").attack)` and it will probably work. What value were you *expecting* it to have?

Comment: @CodingIntrigue I want to get the value that attack gets assigned in envelope.js. its from a range input element.

Comment: @evolutionxbox no.

Comment: @user2952238 In that case you have to wait for the input/change event to occur. The property is initialised with `undefined` and immediately read in your code, the `set` call will happen asynchronously

Comment: Oh, and in the current code, `this` in `set` will refer to the DOM element, not to the `EnvelopeModule` instance.

Comment: @Bergi Ok, i understand. whats the best way of "wait"? Im well aware of that "this" in set refer to the DOM, since i want to get the val() from an input in the DOM.

Comment: I am unsure what you want to do. Do you want to get the current value, the one after the first input event, or all values after each event? And what do you want to do with it? If all you need to do is log it, just put the `console.log` statement inside the `set` method

Comment: @Bergi I want to get the value and set it, wich ive done. i know get and set the value every time the input field change. what i want to is to be able to access the value from outside envelope.js. i want to access it from index.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send your friend to the post office to pick up a package. As soon as he steps out the door, you call his cell phone and ask, "Hey, what was in that package?" Your friend answer, "I have no idea. I'm not at the post office yet." You could call your friend every ten minutes and see if he got it yet, but that's a bad idea because

1. it will eat up time that your friend could be doing something useful, and
2. it could cause a delay: if you call again right before he gets the package, you wait another nine minutes before you find out what's in the package

Instead, you tell your friend *call you* as soon as he gets the package. There's no wasted time, and you find out what's inside as soon as he picks it up.

So, what does that story have to do with your code?

The `attack` property only holds a meaningful value when an `input` or `change` event takes place on `input#attack` element. You're asking for the `attack` value immediately, before any meaningful event has taken place. Instead, you can simply wait: `attack` holds a meaningful value only when your `set` function runs.

If you want `index.js` to specify some arbitrary code to run every time `attack` changes, you can do this by passing a function as an argument to your constructor:

```
export default class EnvelopeModule {
  constructor(attack, runMeWhenAttackChanges) {
    this.attack = attack;
    this.runMeWhenAttackChanges = runMeWhenAttackChanges;
    this.init();        
  }

  init() {
    this.addListeners();
  }

  addListeners() {
    $('input#attack').on('input change', this.set.bind(this));
  }

  set(e) {
    this.attack = $(e.currentTarget).val()/100;
    let val = $(e.currentTarget).val()/100;
    $('input#attack').prev().text(val);
    this.runMeWhenAttackChanges();
  }
}
```

(Note that I fixed an error in how you were handling `this` in `addListeners` and `set`.)

Then, inside your `index.js` provide that `runMeWhenAttackChanges` function:

```
const envelope = new EnvelopeModule(undefined, function() {
    console.log(this.attack);
});
```

The value of `this.attack` will be meaningful only inside the callback function. Any operations that require the most recent value of `attack` should be run from inside that callback. This callback does not run immediately, and it may run many times, long after the surrounding code has finished. You can think of this callback as a set of instructions to run every time `attack` changes, and we've encapsulated those instructions in a function. (To go back to the original metaphor, this is your friend calling you each time he picks up a package.)

Comment: Now you'll need to use `e.currentTarget.value` instead of `$(this).val()` though

Comment: Wow, thanks for your effort. I have now implemented your changes. When i run "this.runMeWhenAttackChanges" from "set" i get this error, even tho the function is defined: "Uncaught TypeError: this.runMeWhenAttackChanges is not a function"

Comment: @user2952238 Did you change `this.set` to `this.set.bind(this)` as I did? The reason that `this.runMeWhenAttackChanges` might be that `this` is still the DOM input element, not the `EnvelopeModule` instance. Also note the changes within `set` itself: adding an argument `e`, and changing two instances of `$(this)` to `$(e.currentTarget)`.

Comment: @apsillers Yes, and i added the corrections mentioned now. Im not getting an error anymore, but the console.log in index.js ' const envelope = new EnvelopeModule'... does not run.

Comment: @user2952238 Works for me in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/nzmtr7qb/ Make sure that your script runs after `<input id=attack>` is added to the DOM -- if it doesn't exist at the time you run `new EnvelopeModule`, then `$('input#attack').on('input change', ...)` won't bind the listener to the element (since it doesn't exist yet).